# Jogging in 90 degree heat

Tags: jogging

Went for a 5km jog at 4pm today in Cambodia (90 degree heat) and my girlfriend got muscle cramps the same as yesterday. She stopped and then went jogging at around 5pm with no problems. 
Started to eat more salt due to the sweating like a pig at the end of it (englishman).
My legs never feel that great either jogging in the heat, but i've got a bad back anyway.

Also, she's been jogging like this for awile now but got abit disheartened that she hasn't lost any weight (although she only weighs 50kgs). She's well pissed off about that.

I'm abit worried she's gonna pack it in, but i reckon she should just run abit later and she'll be fine.

Is the above normal? I thought we might just be a couple of lightweights but then today i read they banned distance running in Florida during the summer because of the heat so maybe we aint that bad.

Is there a limit one should run at certain temperatures for normal non athlete fokes like us?

Cheers

Comment: Can you cut down the fluff in your explanation a little and summarise your one question in a sentence at the end?

Answer (score -1):

Muscle cramps are mostly caused by premature fatigue but the hour that you work out is not that important.Here is a tip on how to stop them :

- Train
- Rest
- Stretching the muscles `Very important`
- Drink pickle juice or another salty solution
- Stay hydrated

  And this is to support my claims and some more information about cramps:
  https://bengreenfieldfitness.com/2013/09/ways-to-stop-muscle-cramps/

---

And as for training in the heat, as doctor Emil Hodzovic said "Performance will always suffer proportionally to an increase in temperature"but there are some hints on how to help you keep cool while training:

- Hydrate above and beyond what you expect you’ll need sweat needs to be replaced and you’ll lose litres an hour, far more than you can absorb by drinking,continue glugging even after you’ve showered, and switching to an electrolyte drink if it’s been a heavy session.They won’t improve or extend your performance, but may aid recovery.
- If you experience lightheadedness, hot or red skin, blurry vision, extreme fatigue, weakness, an excessive heart rate or vomiting, then rest in the shade and rehydrate.
- When there’s more water in the air, less evaporates from your skin, which impacts your natural cooling systems. In humid heat, sweat becomes less effective.

Comment: Nobody really knows what causes cramps. Strtching has not been proven to help, and pickle juice is broscience. Ben Greenfield is not the best source, he has a unique view of science.

Comment: I had severe problems with cramps and I jogged in severe heat and cold with a 20kg vest on me for a long time,bioscience or not this has really helped me or while I started doing this some angel from the sky touched me because my cramps are rare.

Comment: There are things that I do that work for me. Doesn't mean they are proven science. And stretching has def proven inconclusive for cramping prevention.